# How do I convert a mercurial queue patch to uncomitted changes in my working copy?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have an applied patch in my Mercurial queue, how do I convert this patch into uncommited changes in my working copy (as though I'd never created the patch using qnew)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell Mercurial to refresh the patch but exclude all files.  This will leave all changes in the patch uncommitted in your working folder.  You are left with an empty applied patch that can be popped off and deleted.

```
hg qref -X *
hg qpop -f
hg qdel <patch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the absence of other answers, here's what I ended up doing:

First pop the patch off the patch stack so it is no longer applied

```
hg qpop thepatchname --keep-changes
```

I'm not sure if the `--keep-changes` was necessary, but I had local uncommitted changes I wanted to keep.

Next I had to shelve some uncommitted changes in my working copy so I could apply a patch

```
hg shelve
```

Now apply the patch, stored in .hg/patches using the `import` command, with the --no-commit option so the patch is not commited to your repository.

```
hg import .hg/patches/thepatchname --no-commit
```

You can now delete the patch if you like.